# Use Uniswap V3 SwapRouter via Web3

Tags: web3.py, uniswap

I am trying to invoke a swap using Uniswap V3 SwapRouter.exactInputSingle via web3py. Unfortunately it is throwing me a pretty generic error message.

Also I have to manually sign the TX because I am running the script on the Ropsten testnet, so I first have to build the TX via .buildTransaction(...). But it keeps failing. Anyone has an idea what is going wrong here?

```py
    params = {
    'tokenIn': WETH_ADDR,
    'tokenOut': ENS_ADDR,
    'fee': 3000,
    'recipient': WALLET_ADDR,
    'deadline': int((datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=20)).timestamp()),
    'amountIn': Web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),
    'amountOutMinimum': 0,
    'sqrtPriceLimitX96': 0,
    }

    tx_params = {
        # what is this even used for?
        'value': w3.toWei(0.000001, 'ether'),
    }

    router_instance.functions.exactInputSingle(
        params
    ).buildTransaction(
        tx_params
    )
```

Running the script above yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/trade.py", line 92, in <module>
    router_instance.functions.exactInputSingle(
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1081, in buildTransaction
    return build_transaction_for_function(
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1650, in build_transaction_for_function
    prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(web3, prepared_transaction)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 102, in fill_transaction_defaults
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 66, in <lambda>
    'gas': lambda web3, tx: web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 735, in estimate_gas
    return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 187, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 167, in formatted_response
    apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 67, in apply_error_formatters
    formatted_resp = pipe(response, error_formatters)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "/home/niklas/Projects/binance-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/_utils/method_formatters.py", line 573, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
    raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. Most likely the testnet did not have a pool for (WETH, ENS). After I forked an Infura mainnet with Ganache, I had all the contracts I needed.